# Doubly linked list segmentation fault printing backwards

Tags: c, file, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete a node at a specific location but I keep getting a segmentation fault 11.

I am reading the position and value from a file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  float val;
  struct node *prev;
  struct node *next;
}node_t;

void printForward(node_t *head) {
  node_t *current = head;

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%.2f\n", current->val);
    current = current->next;
  }
}

void printBackward(node_t *head) {
  node_t *current = head;

  while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
  }

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%.2f\n", current->val);
    current = current->prev;
  }
}


void deleteAtPos(node_t **head, int pos) {
  int i;
  node_t *current = *head;
  node_t *temp = NULL;

  if (pos == 0) {
    temp = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    (*head) = temp;
    (*head)->prev = NULL;
    return;
  }

    for (i = 0; i < (pos - 1); i++) {
      if (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
      }
    }

      temp = current->next;
      current->next = temp->next;
      free(temp);
}


// Fix insert at position
void insertAtPos(node_t **head, int pos, float val) {
  int i;
  node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  node_t *current = *head;
  newNode->val = val;

  if (pos == 0) {
    newNode->next = (*head);
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    (*head)->prev = newNode;
    (*head) = newNode;
    return;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    if (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    else {
      printf("Node does not exist\n");
      break;
    }
  }

  current->prev->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = current->prev;
  newNode->next = current;
  current->prev = newNode;
}

void addEnd(node_t **head, float val) {
  node_t *current = *head;
  node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  newNode->next = NULL;
  newNode->val = val;

  if (*head == NULL) {
    *head = newNode;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    return;
  }

  while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
  }
  current->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = current;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Error");
  }

  node_t *head = NULL;

  FILE *fp;
  int i = 0, x;
  float valLine1, valLine2, valLine3;
  char buffer[200], *token, *del = ",";
  float posVals[200], delPos[200];
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    while (token != NULL) {
      valLine1 = atof(token);
      addEnd(&head, valLine1);
      token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }

    printForward(head);
    printf("\n");


    del = ":,";
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    while (token != NULL) {
      valLine2 = atof(token);
      posVals[i] = valLine2;
      token = strtok(NULL, del);
      i++;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < i; x += 2) {
      insertAtPos(&head, posVals[x + 1], posVals[x]);
    }
    printForward(head);

    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    i = 0;
    token = strtok(buffer, del);
    while (token != NULL) {
      valLine3 = atof(token);
      delPos[i] = valLine3;
      token = strtok(NULL, del);
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");


    for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
      deleteAtPos(&head, delPos[x]);
    }



    printForward(head);
    printf("\n");
    printBackward(head);

    fclose(fp);


}
```

The trouble is with my deleteAtPos function but I can't figure out why.

Here is the output:

```
24.00
0.04
17.00
-200.10
34.60
0.00
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And here is the contents of the file:

```
17,32.5,12,0,34.6,-200.1,17,0.04,24
1:2,4.1:5,-12:4
3,5,0
```

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: Check your logic for last node. You are going to put value in Null, Current->next = temp->next. It is wrong

Comment: Yes I thought so too and I tried many different ways but I could not make it work. I am actually trying to print the list backwards and that's what keeps giving me a seg fault. Do I need to do anything with prev in my delete function?

Comment: Why don't you stop your loop just before node that need to be delete? Because you have to. Maintain prev pointer too or you can just copy the contents of next node and delate that one instead of specific node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your deleteAtPos() function now you can delete at any position and your backward() function will print correct values.

```
void deleteAtPos(node_t **head, int pos) {
  int i;
  node_t *current = *head;
  node_t *temp = NULL;    

  if (pos == 0) {
    temp = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    (*head) = temp;
    (*head)->prev = NULL;
    return;
  }

    for (i = 0; i < (pos - 1); i++) {
      if (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
      }
    }


    temp = current;
    if(current->next==NULL)
    {
        current->prev->next = current->next;
    }
    else
    {
        current->prev->next = current->next;
        current->next->prev = current->prev;
    }

    free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying the trouble is with `deleteAtPos`.  But your code is very far from an SSCCE, so I don't want to isolate the problem for you - you should do that, and most of the time, during the process of isolation, you will find the answer.  If not, you can then post the question here.

Therefore I will just list the things I can see are wrong with `deleteAtPos` and maybe if you fix all of them, the problem will disappear.

1. You are not handling the situation where `*head` is NULL, the list has 0 elements. This would surely segfault.
2. You are not checking that `pos >= 0`.
3. You are not correctly handling the case where your list has one element, either.  Another segfault.
4. You are not correctly handling the case where `pos` is the end of your list.  Another segfault.